# Find word in link regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to match the link which contain specific text using regex?
I need to add some text after href value.
I tried to match "word" in following link:

```
<a href="http://word/sth">some link</a>
```

I tried this, but without success:

```
(https?:\/\/[^word"]+)
```

Comment: `/https?:\/\/(word)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an option you could use the DOM instead of a regex:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<a href="http://word/sth">some link</a>';
if (div.firstChild.innerHTML.indexOf("some") !== -1) {
  console.log("contains some!");
  div.firstChild.href += " added text";
}
console.log(div.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need ^ and $
Also the brackets are to match a single character in the given set.

Try just:

```
https?:\/\/(word)
```

Helpful resource: You can test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: just did, sorry, i was checking it in the web i posted. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: I wasn't sure if this is what OP wanted, so just wanted some feedback from OP if this is what he is looking for. You don't need to remove it.

Comment: Yeah this that's what I needed